# I just installed Angular Material and Angular Animations in my project and got these errors

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just ran the code: `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/animations`

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "cerpnew",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/angular-material": "^1.1.54",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.6.0",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-checkbox": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.10",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.55.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "select-picker": "^0.3.1",
    "sweetalert": "^2.0.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.13",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

When running `ng serve` I get the following errors.

> ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts
> (9,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple-renderer.d.ts
> (9,26): Cannot find module '@angular/ cdk/platform'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete.d.ts
> (10,44): Cannot find module '@angular/c dk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts
> (8,32): Cannot find module '@an gular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts
> (9,67): Cannot find module '@an gular/cdk/overlay'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts
> (9,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
>
> ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts
> (11,30): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts
> (11,30): Cannot find module '@angular /cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts
> (12,43): Cannot find module '@angular /cdk/collections'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts
> (4,30): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
>
> ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip.d.ts
> (8,33): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts
> (8,33): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts
> (9,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts
> (10,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/collect ions'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-config.d.ts
> (9,27): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bid i'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts
> (10,86): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk /portal'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts
> (11,34): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk /a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-ref.d.ts
> (8,28): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overla y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts
> (1,62): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts
> (2,31): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts
> (8,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bi di'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts
> (9,67): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/ov erlay'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/accordion-item.d.ts
> (9,43): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk /collections'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts
> (2,43): Cannot find module '@angular/cd k/collections'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel-header.d.ts
> (1,30): Cannot find module '@ang ular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/grid-list/typings/grid-list.d.ts
> (10,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bid i'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/autosize.d.ts
> (9,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform' . ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/input.d.ts
> (10,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts
> (8,50): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y '. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts
> (9,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/coll ections'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-item.d.ts
> (8,33): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-panel.d.ts
> (10,27): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-directive.d.ts
> (9,27): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi '. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-trigger.d.ts
> (1,43): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
>
> ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-trigger.d.ts
> (2,67): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overla y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/progress-spinner/typings/progress-spinner.d.ts
> (10,26): Cannot find module '@a ngular/cdk/platform'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts
> (11,43): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/collections '. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts
> (12,30): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts
> (8,44): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple.d.ts
> (9,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platf orm'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts
> (10,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/collectio ns'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts
> (11,109): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay' . ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts
> (9,34): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts
> (10,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts
> (9,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cd k/platform'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts
> (12,30): Cannot find module '@angular/c dk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/slider/typings/slider.d.ts
> (8,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/slider/typings/slider.d.ts
> (12,30): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-config.d.ts
> (9,36): Cannot find module '@angular/c dk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-config.d.ts
> (10,27): Cannot find module '@angular/ cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-container.d.ts
> (10,70): Cannot find module '@angul ar/cdk/portal'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-ref.d.ts
> (8,28): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/ overlay'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar.d.ts
> (8,31): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y '. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar.d.ts
> (9,25): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/over lay'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar.d.ts
> (10,31): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/por tal'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/sort/typings/sort-header.d.ts
> (9,30): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/table'.
>
> ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-label.d.ts
> (9,30): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/stepp er'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts
> (1,37): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/stepper' . ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper-button.d.ts
> (1,52): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/s tepper'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts
> (8,30): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y '. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts
> (9,84): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/table'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/table.d.ts
> (1,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/table'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/row.d.ts
> (1,66): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/table'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-label.d.ts
> (9,41): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab.d.ts
> (8,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-body.d.ts
> (10,53): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-body.d.ts
> (11,43): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-header.d.ts
> (8,43): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-header.d.ts
> (13,31): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/scrolli ng'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts
> (8,32): Cannot find module '@angular /cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts
> (9,26): Cannot find module '@angular /cdk/platform'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.d.ts
> (10,31): Cannot find module '@angula r/cdk/scrolling'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/typings/tooltip.d.ts
> (9,31): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/typings/tooltip.d.ts
> (10,32): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/typings/tooltip.d.ts
> (11,156): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overla y'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/typings/tooltip.d.ts
> (12,26): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platfor m'. ERROR in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/typings/tooltip.d.ts
> (13,34): Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/scrolli ng'. ERROR in Error:
> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not
> resolve @angular/cdk/observers relative to E:/angular2/CER
> PNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/index.d.ts.,
> resolving symbol MatCheckboxModule in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@
> angular/material/checkbox/typings/index.d.ts, resolving symbol
> MatCheckboxModule in
> E:/angular2/CERPNEW/node_modules/@angular/material/che
> ckbox/typings/index.d.ts
> at syntaxError (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
> at simplifyInContext (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25118:23)
> at StaticReflector.simplify (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25130:13)
> at StaticReflector.annotations (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24558:41)
> at _getNgModuleMetadata (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
> at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
> at E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
> at Array.reduce ()
> at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
> at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
> at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
> at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
> at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (E:\angular2\CERPNEW\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)
> at 
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: Please note angularjs tag is for Angular 1.x, for other it is angular

Answer (score 117, accepted):

you should install neccessary *@angular/cdk* library to correct use of the newest @angular/material.

You can do this by command:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

Comment: After this command, the error was still there till I restarted the ng server by the command [ng serve]

Comment: @zeeawan you can try this also: tsconfig.json, in angularCompilerOptions have set ("enableIvy": false)

Comment: doesn't work for me..
gives same error after ng serve

Comment: even after this I'm facing the same error

Answer (score 13):

Get into the Workspace or Angular project you are working with, open command prompt and run the below command:

**npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk**

If the error is still not gone, try clearing the cache by the given command :

**npm cache clear --force**

Another approach to clean the cache is by manually deleting it from the file system at

**C:\Users\%USER_PROFILE_NAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache**

Try deleting everything from the above location then rerun

**npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk**

Hopefully this should solve your issue and `ngServe` would show the message about successful compilation of project.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I got my solution already just in the first answer.

Comment: Hi tried doing all the above but still unable to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

I had faced the same issue. Problem is that you used `npm i @angular/material` to install Angular Material.
Use `ng add @angular/material` as shown in the documentation page.
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

This will automatically install the CDK and other dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, for Angular 9+ (but maybe also for 8, not tested) `ng add @angular/material` should solve all those issues adding everything that is needed to have Material ready to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Setting "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
}
```

Comment: that might just mask the real problem

Answer (score 2):

There are questions the package stops and asks you before it installs, and I did not realize that. I started the installation process and then started to work in another terminal/window.  When I got those error messages, I did not realize that the package was hanging on those questions in the first terminal.  Once I answered them, the package finished installing and those errors went away.

Answer (score 2):

you need to:
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

**then** restart the server `ng serve --port 4100 -o` the `-o` to auto launch the app in new tab