# An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@angular/material/menu"

Tags: .net, angular

I am new to angular.After reaching to clientapp folder of my project,I have used command called 'ng serve'.
I am getting an error.
Your global Angular CLI version (12.2.9) is greater than your local version (11.2.18). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".(Yellow color msg)
An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@angular/material/menu" has missing dependencies:

- @angular/cdk/a11y
- @angular/cdk/coercion
- @angular/cdk/keycodes
- @angular/cdk/portal
- @angular/cdk/bidi
- @angular/cdk/overlay
- @angular/cdk/platform
- @angular/cdk/scrolling (in red color).
  So again I have used npm install command and ng serve.Still getting this error.

What shall I do now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am new to angular. I just installed angular material and angular animations in my small project and got some of the errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885008/i-am-new-to-angular-i-just-installed-angular-material-and-angular-animations-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your global Angular CLI version (12.2.9) is greater than your local
> version (11.2.18). The local Angular CLI version is used.

Angular cli is producing this warning because your project is build with `11.2.18` while your globally installed version is `12.2.9`. You can ignore this warning because your project will use locally installed `11.2.18` version present in `node-modules` folder.

> An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point
> "@angular/material/menu" has missing dependencies:

You are getting this error because some of the modules of `@angular/material` internally depend on `@angular/cdk` package.

Try installing `@angular/cdk` package with:

```
npm install --save @angular/cdk
```

If the error still persists, force clean the cache & delete `node-modules` folder.

```
npm cache clear --force
```

After this, run the `npm install` command. It will download all your project dependencies again.